# Trying to toggle between read and unread

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am trying to have my button say read or unread when a user clicks on it I've tried adding my readBookfunction to the onclick but I get an error like this, any help would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

I want it to look like this below and have the button either be read or unread

[image]

script.js

```js
class Book {
  constructor(title, author, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.read = read;

    addBookToLibrary(this);
  }
}

let myLibrary = [];

const table = document.getElementById('libraryTable');

let hiddenForm = document.getElementById('hiddenForm')
//toggles the input form opacity and z-index
function showForm() {
  hiddenForm.classList.toggle('active')
}

function clearInput() {
  inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
  for (let i in inputs) {
    inputs[i].value = ''
  }
}

function createBook() {
  new Book(document.getElementById('title').value,
    document.getElementById('author').value,
    document.getElementById('read').value);
}

const harrypotter = new Book('Harry Potter', 'JK Rowling', 'read')
const stripedpajamas = new Book('The Boy in the Striped pajamas', 'John Boyne', 'read')
const randomBook = new Book('The random book', 'random author', 'read')

function addBookToLibrary(book) {
  myLibrary.push(book);
}

function readBook(Book) {
  let position = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
    if (Book.title == myLibrary[i].title) {
      position = i;
    }
  }

  if (myLibrary[position].read == 'read') {
    myLibrary[position].read = "unread";
  } else {
    myLibrary[position].read = "read";
  }
  return myLibrary[position].read;
}

function displayBooks() {
  table.textContent = '';

  for (i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
    let newRow = table.insertRow(i);
    newRow.insertCell(0).innerText = myLibrary[i].title;
    newRow.insertCell(1).innerText = myLibrary[i].author;
    newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = `<button onclick='${i}' class='tableButtons' >${myLibrary[i].read}</button>`
    newRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = `<button onclick='removeBook(${i})' class='tableButtons' >Delete</button>`
  }
}

function removeBook(index) {
  if (index > 1) {
    myLibrary.splice(index, index - 1);
  } else if (index == 1) {
    myLibrary.splice(index, index);
  } else if (index == 0) {
    myLibrary.shift();
  }

}

const displayButton = document.querySelector(".display");

displayButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  displayBooks();
});
```

Comment: I've tidied your code up a little (removing quite a lot of white-space to make it a little more compact, and easier to read), and converted your posted code into a working Snippet, although it doesn't currently work because of a `TypeError: displayButton is null`. Could you correct the error to make it easier for those that wish to help to be able to do so? @Daksh: please don't edit questions to make them *less* useful.